# Calling `(get-thread-binding)` results in a stack overflow

Tags: clojure

When I run

> user> (get-thread-bindings)

I see

> StackOverflowError   clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap$BitmapIndexedNode.index (PersistentHashMap.java:677)

This is with a fresh `lein new foo` project, where I have a single line

> (def foo "Hello World")

The stack trace has repeated calls to `clojure.core/pr-on` and `clojure.core/print-map`, etc. but the initial call that triggered this isn't visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you evaluate expressions in the REPL, the results of the three most recent expressions are stored in special thread-bound vars named `*1`, `*2`, and `*3`. Those vars are included in the map returned by `get-thread-bindings`, because they are thread-bound. In particular, `*1` is a map of all thread-bound vars, one of whose values is the var `*1` again.

It's okay for such a circular reference to exist in memory, but when you try to *print* it to the REPL, you will have trouble, because it looks like an infinitely deep tree. Instead, if you want to look around at the map returned by `(get-thread-bindings)`, you will have to be a little bit more careful to only look at parts of it which are not infinite. For example, here's what I did to double-check that my answer to your question was correct:

```
user=> (class (get-thread-bindings))
clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
user=> (keys (get-thread-bindings))
(#<Var: --unnamed--> #<Var: --unnamed--> #'clojure.core/*assert* #'clojure.core/*compile-path* #'clojure.core/*math-context* #'clojure.test/*test-out* #'clojure.core/*out* #<Var: --unnamed--> #'clojure.core/*2 #'clojure.core/*source-path* #'clojure.core/*err* #'clojure.core/*data-readers* #<Var: --unnamed--> #'clojure.core/*command-line-args* #<Var: --unnamed--> #'clojure.core/*warn-on-reflection* #'clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/*msg* #'clojure.core/*read-eval* #'clojure.core/*default-data-reader-fn* #'clojure.core/*1 #'clojure.core/*unchecked-math* #'clojure.core/*e #'clojure.core/*file* #'clojure.core/*print-length* #'clojure.core/*3 #<Var: --unnamed--> #<Var: --unnamed--> #<Var: --unnamed--> #'clojure.core/*ns* #'clojure.core/*print-level* #<Var: --unnamed--> #<Var: --unnamed--> #<Var: --unnamed--> #'clojure.core/*in* #'clojure.core/*print-meta* #'clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session/*out-limit*)
user=> (map (comp :name meta) (keys (get-thread-bindings)))
(nil nil *assert* *compile-path* *math-context* *test-out* *out* nil *2 *source-path* *err* *data-readers* nil *command-line-args* nil *warn-on-reflection* *msg* *read-eval* *default-data-reader-fn* *1 *unchecked-math* *e *file* *print-length* *3 nil nil nil *ns* *print-level* nil nil nil *in* *print-meta* *out-limit*)
```

Circular structures are a bit of a pain in a data-oriented language like Clojure, because you're used to being able to print anything to see what it's all about, and you can't print these. But you can still investigate them, as I did above, by seeing what class they are, and then investigating them in some way that works with that class (eg, for a map, looking at its keys is typically a good idea).

Supposing that Stack Overflow didn't exist, or you were stuck on a space station with no Internet access, how could you have discovered the `*1` phenomenon yourself? Once you saw that it was impossible to print all of `get-thread-bindings`, you could have discovered that it was a map, and then looked around at its keys to see which of them explode when you print them and which don't. Then you could look further into the explosive one (`*1`), and discovered that it was another map, which contained another key named `*1` whose value was another map...Hopefully this gives you some idea of how to debug similar issues in the future.